# 'fetch' Response.status and Response.ok, are they supported on mobile browsers?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, fetch-api

Assume the following snippet:

```js
  fetch('someurl')
    .then(response => {
      if (response.status !== 200) {
        throw new Error('failed');
      }
    });
```

Reviewing 'can I use': https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_response_status
And MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/status both note that these (.ok as well) are not supported on mobile browsers such as chrome and iOS.

Can this really be true?

On the other hand, I would have assumed all browsers (excluding IE) fully support the fetch spec. So what am I missing here?

Comment: I have a hard time believing that a browser might implement the `fetch` API without a complete `Response` API. It's certainly possible, but seems rather unlikely. Take a look at the [version history of the data](https://github.com/mdn/browser-compat-data/commits/master/api/Response.json), maybe it's just outdated. In any case, try it yourself if you have access to one of these browsers, and [file a bug report](https://github.com/mdn/browser-compat-data/blob/master/docs/contributing.md)!

Comment: I have tested (on mobile chrome) and it's working as expected. Still, the conflicting documentation is alarming. So I'm hopeful someone will be able to clarify it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes this is the case. Looking at the support more specifically:

`.ok` and `.status` are not supported in numerous mobile browsers

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/status and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/ok

It is likely because these features are still listed as "experimental."

(As a JS developer myself, I was actually really surprised to learn this too)

Comment: The two pages you linked are just showing the data from the same source that the OP linked. Do you have any other evidence to support these claims?